# Reading ReactNative App version from javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, react-native, react-native-ios

I am wondering there is a way to access the applications version name/number via javascript in a react native application. I have a snippet of javascript which I inject into an application but I want to know the version of the application before I do some processing. Is there a straightforward way of doing this? I understand that I can use a module and then import that into an application.

The problem is that I have a javascript snippet that is downloaded over the air and injected into my application's WebView. However there are certain things that aren't available in the older versions of the application.

I want the javascript snippet to read the applications version number.

Is there a potential way around this?

Comment: you can `import packageJson from './package.json';` in your react native app to get the package `version` and `name`. If you are making a request, you can pass the version number to your server api/url to download version specific payload.